# How many integers can be stored in this 2-dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm studying for my exams and I've bumped into a problem I can't solve.
The question here is "How many different int-values can be stored in the two dimensional array "arr" after running the code?"

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][];
arr[0] = new int[5];

for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
{
arr[i] = arr[i-1];
}
```

I thought the answer was 7, and here's why:
You create the 2-D array "arr" and immediately declare that it has 3 open values in 1 dimension.
Then you say that the the first open value becomes an array itself, containing 5 open values.
Then finally, the for-loop says that the second value of the original array becomes the first value and the same goes for the third value of the original array. (These values weren't initialized, so it boils down to 0 becoming 0 since that's the standard value for an integer)

Which gives 7.

Though the answer should be 5 according to my book, and I can't find why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is the historical term of **reference** in java - the arr[i] is not holding a **copy** of arr[i-1] but a **reference** (points to the same memory as arr[i-1]) to the array, so any changes to arr[i-1] reflect instantly on arr[i] and vice versa. It is more complicated than this, but basicaly that's all. :) [Helper tutorial with image explaining reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's 5 because each of the 3 positions of the outer array contain a reference to the same 5 element array. So after executing the code in your question, if one were to do this:

```
arr[0][0] = 5;
```

Then the following would hold:

```
arr[0][0] == 5; // true
arr[1][0] == 5; // true
arr[2][0] == 5; // true
```

Where you say `the for-loop says that the second value of the original array becomes the first value and the same goes for the third value of the original array. (These values weren't initialized, so it boils down to 0 becoming 0 since that's the standard value for an integer)` you're mostly correct except `arr[0]` was initialized. It was set to `new int[5]`.

After the code in your post runs this is what the array looks like:

[image: Picture of 2 dimensional array]

Even though the array is of type `int[][]`, the 3 elements in the outer array don't hold `int`s, they hold references to `int[]`s.

Comment: So saying arr[i] = arr[i-1] doesn't make the value of the actual integer in [i] the value of the integer in [i-1] but rather copies whatever is in [i-1] (In this case an array) and puts it in [i]? If this is the case then I'm still not sure how you can only store 5 values, since the question is "After running the code". Intuitively I'd say that we now have a 5x3 array with 15 different values... [Edit] Just saw your edit, going to read it first and if I still have questions I'll reply again.

Comment: You have a 3x5 array but the 5s are all the same. I'll draw a picture that will make it easier to visualize, give me a sec and I'll edit my post.

Comment: I see now, I was confusing arr[0] and arr[0][0]. One more question though: The reference to the array in the first, second and third position of the original array is kept after running the code? It doesn't just take all the values from the one and put it in the other but actually creates a permanent reference? So I would basically just get 3 arrays that are exactly the same?

Comment: Ok, edited to add picture and some more explanation.

Comment: Kind of. You would actually have 3 different ways of accessing the same 5 element array.

Answer (score 6):

Explanation inline, with comments

```
/* Declare a two dimensional array, but only specify the first dimension
 * of '3'.  This effectively leaves three arrays of undefined length
 * to which 'arr' can point.
 */
int[][] arr = new int[3][];

/* Declare that arr[0] - the first element in the outer dimension
 * is a array of length 5.  This creates 5 locations in an array of 
 * length 5 into which integers can be stored.
 */
arr[0] = new int[5];

/* No further declarations creating new space to store data in arr.
 * With no additional operations, below, to allocate memory, there
 * may never be more than 5 locations in arr to store anything.
 * This means that the rest of the question, as written, is like the
 * extra garbage you sometimes get in word problems, to try and confuse 
 * you
 * 
 *    "A train, carrying 1000 apples, is traveling from Des Moines to Boston
 *     at 90mph.  B train, carrying 1 apple, is traveling from Boston to Des Moines
 *     at 30mph on exactly teh same track.  At what point on the track do they
 *     crash?"
 *
 *    The apples are unnecessary to the problem at hand.
 */

/* Iterate through arr - the outer array of length 3. */
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    /* Set the current value of arr[i] to the value stored at arr[i-1].
     * Remember what each value of arr[] is before entering the loop...
     *    arr[0] = an array of length 5, whose values are not yet explicitly set
     *    arr[1] = null
     *    arr[2] = null
     */
    arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    /* The first time we get this far, arr[1] will have been set to arr[0]...
     *    arr[0] = array length 5
     *    arr[1] = the same length 5 array pointed to by arr[0]
     *    arr[2] = null
     *
     * The second time we get this far, arr[1] will have been set to arr[0]...
     *    arr[0] = array length 5
     *    arr[1] = the same length 5 array pointed to by arr[0]
     *    arr[2] = the same length 5 array pointed to by arr[0]
     */
}
```